# How to extract data from the html output using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, parsing, automation

```
>$op.Content
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//j3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head><meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<title>Index of generic-releases/upgrades/sw/release</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of generic-releases/upgrades/sw/release</h1>
<pre>Name       Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="10.4.0.30/">10.4.0.30/</a>  14-jan-2020 15:08    -
<a href="10.4.0.34/">10.4.0.34/</a>  14-jan-2020 20:19    -
<a href="10.5.0.46/">10.5.0.46/</a>  27-jan-2020 18:43    -
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory Online Server at xxx.jfrog.io Port 80</address> 
</body></html>
```

1)Above is the html page with the list of software version folders
2)I want the output to be displayed according to latest time and date as shown below using powershell

```
10.5.0.46  27-jan-2020 18:43
10.4.0.34  14-jan-2020 20:19
10.4.0.30  14-jan-2020 15:08
```

3)Can anyone please help me how to achieve this output using powershell

Answer (score 1):

As @Doug mentioned, it is generally a bad idea to peek and/or poke in serialized files directly, instead, it is better to use a proper (html) parser to retrieve your data.

To give you an example using the [`IHTMLDocument2 interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v=vs.85)):

```
$Doc = New-Object -Com 'HTMLFile'
$Unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Content)
if ($Doc.IHTMLDocument2_Write) { $Doc.IHTMLDocument2_Write($Unicode) } else { $Doc.write($Unicode) }

$Pres = $Doc.getElementsByTagName('pre')
$Headers = $Pres[0].innerText -Split '\s\s+'
$Pres[1].childNodes | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.tagName -eq 'A') { $A = $_ }
    elseif ($_.nodeValue -is [string]) {
        $Data = ($A.innerText + $_.nodeValue) -Split '\s\s+'
        $Properties = [ordered]@{}
        $i = 0
        Foreach ($Header in $Headers) {
            if ( $Data -le $i) { $Properties[$Header] = $Data[$i++] }
        }
        [pscustomobject]$Properties
    }
} | Sort-Object { $_.'Last modified' -as [DateTime] } -Descending
```

```
Name       Last modified     Size
----       -------------     ----
10.5.0.46/ 27-jan-2020 18:43 -…
10.4.0.34/ 14-jan-2020 20:19 -…
10.4.0.30/ 14-jan-2020 15:08 -…
../…
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to try and parse HTML manually. There are HTML parsing libraries that exist for this purpose. For your simple example, you *could* get your desired results with regex. It is assumed that $op.Content is an array of strings. If it is actually one string, we'd need to make a slight adjustment.

```
$results = switch -Regex ($op.Content){
    '>(.+?)/.+?\s+(.+?)\s{2,}' {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP   = $Matches.1
            Date = $matches.2 -as [datetime]
        }
    }
}

$results | Sort-Object -Property date -Descending
```

Output on my machine

```
IP        Date                 
--        ----                 
10.5.0.46 2020-01-27 6:43:00 PM
10.4.0.34 2020-01-14 8:19:00 PM
10.4.0.30 2020-01-14 3:08:00 PM
```